# Is "Virus" a part of Acaryote?

Tags: cell-biology, virology

I am just a beginner of BIOLOGY as a Grade 7 student! 
But the information which I got from my textbook and Internet has got me confused as MY TEXTBOOK SAID:-

> Viruses are part of "Akaryote"

And **'Acaryote'** (or **'Akaryote'** or however **'Akaryocyte')** is just a Smaller group of *ORGANISM* than **Prokaryote.** Example:- Blood (As said in Wikipedia)

Pic-1:- A VIRUS DECRIPTION BY **BBC**
[image: Picture-1] 
 
(***END OF PICTURE 1***)

Answer (score 1):

*Akaryote* is not used for a group of organisms in the way that *prokaryotes* and *eukaryotes* are used.  The word *akaryote* is not a common word, but when used it is a synonym for *akaryocyte* meaning "a cell that does not have a nucleus" and is used in the context of eukaryotes, in which cells normally do have a nucleus.  (It is not used in the context of a prokaryote, which does not have a nucleus but does have a cell, or in the context of a virus, which does not even have a cell.)

The diagrams in your question have confused two different things.  The first illustration is indeed a virus, as stated.  The remaining illustrations are not of a virus, though.  You may have thought they were visually similar, but they are not similar in the details.  The "fibres" may look like like "flagella", but they are different.  The virus is not a cell and has no cell membrane. Viruses are not prokaryotes.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake of Visual Identification, However I could not find any helpful INFORMATION about "Akaryote"...... Also thanks for helping....